# Model data source - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I'm trying to model a data source in power bi, but I'm not getting it.

Could you help me with alternatives so I can create a new column? The data source is in excel and brings the data with subtotal by types (XPTO, XPT, etc). I want to put these types as corresponding values ​​in the new column for your items. I tried via power query and dax, but I could not.

Original Source:
[image: Original Source]

Modifications Needed
[image: Modifications Needed]

[Source File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuUNmh5pyq5g9QI_hoNQewiZRJ0b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that you can identify the Subtotal Rows by checking the position of the first space in the first column:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added RowType" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "RowType", each Text.PositionOf([#"Centro financ./item orçamento"]," "), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Type" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added RowType", "Type", each if [RowType] = 4 then Text.BetweenDelimiters([#"Centro financ./item orçamento"], "  ", " ") else null, type text),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Type",{"Type"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([RowType] = 8)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"RowType"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",List.Combine({{"Type"}, Table.ColumnNames(Source)}))
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to - Include another data source in Power BI, which will look something like this.

```
Item                  Type
615x92120 Mat1        XPTA
615x92121 Mat2        XPTA
615x92122 Mat3        XPTU
615x92123 Mat4        XPTU
```

And then do a Join between your existing table and this table to bring out the Type in your existing table. Once you have done that, you should be able to filter out to blanks or null which will be your delete lines.

**Note :- This only works, if you know all the items and corresponding types in advance.**